# How to stop POI from appending the datat while writing onto Excel

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

There are some data in webpage in a tabular format. I want to retrieve all and write into an excel. I have used  a nested for loop. But the code is only writing  only  the last column. While trying to retrieve and write onto the console, I could see that all the elements are being written, That means, although the code is taking all elements, i guess it is somehow appending the data and only keeping the latest column. Code used is below. Please help if possible.

```
    public class FirstTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    XSSFSheet sheet;
    int Rownum;
    FileInputStream  Fis;
    XSSFWorkbook WB;
    FileOutputStream fos;
  @Test
  public void Test1() throws IOException {
      Rownum = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr.one")).size();
      fos = new FileOutputStream("path to excel");

      //System.out.println(Rownum);
      for (int i =0; i<Rownum;i++)
      {       
          for (int j=0;j<=3;j++)
          {
              //System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr//tr["+(j+1)+"]//td["+(i+1)+"]//div")).getText());
              sheet.createRow(i+1).createCell(j).setCellValue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr//tr["+(i+2)+"]//td["+(j+1)+"]//div")).getText());   
          }         

      }   
      WB.write(fos);
      fos.close();  
        }
  @BeforeSuite
  public void beforeSuite() throws IOException {
      WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("https://www.annauniv.edu/dean.php");
        Fis = new FileInputStream("path to excel");
       WB = new XSSFWorkbook(Fis);
       sheet = WB.getSheetAt(0);

  }


  @AfterSuite
  public void afterSuite() throws IOException {

     driver.quit();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sheet.createRow` does exactly what it says. It creates a **new** **empty** row every time it gets called. So all cells which previous were created in that row get lost.

Do:

```
...
XSSFSheet sheet;
XSSFRow row; 
...
for (int i = 0; i < Rownum; i++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(i+1);
    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        //System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr//tr["+(j+1)+"]//td["+(i+1)+"]//div")).getText());
        row.createCell(j).setCellValue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr//tr["+(i+2)+"]//td["+(j+1)+"]//div")).getText());
    }
}
```